I'm getting an error in python : AttributeError: Rectangle.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort_columns'
The following code produces the error mentioned in the title:
`data3 = pd.DataFrame(\
 
 df_all.groupby(by=["Age"])["Customer ID"]\
 
 .count()\
 
 .reset_index(name='Distribution by Age'))

data3.sort_values(\
 by=['Age'], \
 ascending=True,\
 inplace=True)


data3.plot(x='Age',
y=['Distribution by Age'],
kind='bar',
grid = True,
xlabel = 'Age',
ylabel = '# People',
figsize=(12,7),
rot = 0,
title = 'Cust. Distribution by Age',
table = False,
sort_columns = False,
secondary_y = False)``

My goal is to create barplots representing the distribution of customers sorted by age, their overall distribution and the distribution of defaulting customers.

Just delete sort_columns = False, it is not supported by pandas.Dataframe.plot(). Your code performs the sorting before plotting, correctly.
